# How to get a vector of all dates in the current month

Tags: r, date

the goal is quite straightforward, I want a vector made of all the dates in this month.

Why?

Because I'll later be able to transform this vector and get the first day of the month, or alternatively, a vector with just the 1st and 16th of the month, or even a vector with all the Mondays of the month... list goes on, but POSIXlt should serve us better since it also stores the weekday.

---

```
require("lubridate")
v.d.CheckDates <- as.POSIXlt(seq(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date() - days(31)), length.out=62, by="day"))
v.d.CheckDates[v.d.CheckDates$mon == as.numeric(format(Sys.Date() , format = "%m")) - 1]
```

it's basically creating a 62 day vector centered on today (first line) and then trimming the other months (second line)

So, does anyone have a more cleaver and more efficient (preferably also one liner) way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `floor_date` to get 1st date of current month, `ceiling_date` to get 1st date of next month subtract `- 1` to get last day of current month and create sequence.

```
library(lubridate)
todays_date <- Sys.Date()
seq(floor_date(todays_date, 'month'), 
    ceiling_date(todays_date, 'month') - 1, by = 1)
```

---

Also other similar variations,

```
floor_date(todays_date, 'month') + 1:days_in_month(todays_date) - 1

seq(floor_date(todays_date, 'month'), 
               length.out = days_in_month(todays_date), by = 1)
```

This returns object of class `'Date'`, there are function in base R as well as `lubridate` to get whichever part of Date you want.

Answer (score 2):

Package [timeperiodsR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeperiodsR/index.html) has a handy function for that :

```
timeperiodsR::this_month(part = "sequence")
```